# Mocking Entitymanager while testing of EJB class

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mockito

I am using: Netbeans, Glassfish, Mockito

While working with Java EE for the first time I have come across the issue of trying to test methods that interact with the database using an entitymanager.

In the below code snippets I have tried to mock out the entity manager so i know that the db interaction will not be tested exactly and for this testing thats ok. But I am striggling on instansiating the `UsersController` because it has an injected `EntityManager` which is always `null`. I would like the `EntityManager` to be mocked out so I can test the rest of the method.

Below is a class that interacts with the db. NOTE this is an example methods, it is not for use in production.

```
@Stateless
public class UsersController {
    @PersistenceContext()
    EntityManager em;

    public User getOne() {
        em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
        User theUser = null;
        try {
            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("User.findAll");
            Collection<User> entities = q.getResultList();
            theUser = Iterables.get(entities, 1);
        }
        catch(NoResultException e){}
        em.flush();
        return theUser;
    };
}
```

The test file that will test this method.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UsersControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private UsersController usersController;
    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManagerMock;

    private Collection<User> mockUsersDbCollection = //...

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpClass() {

        when(entityManagerMock.createNamedQuery("User.findAll")).thenReturn(mockUsersDbCollection);
    }

    @Test
    public void findOneTest(){
        User mockUserDbEntry = new User("1", "pa$$word", "salt", "user1", "user1@email.com", false);

        User returnedUser = null;
        returnedUser = usersController.getOne();

        assertEquals(returnedUser.getId(), "1");
    }
}
```

Whenever the `UsersController` mock is created the entityManager is always null causing issues, how can I inject the `EntityManagerMock` so it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- you are testing your `UsersController`, therefore it should not be mocked; rather you should use the `@InjectMocks` annotation on it because you want Mockito to inject your mock entity manager
- the `@BeforeClass` annotation only works when applied to a static method, which in turn can only access static instance variables; in this instance I think you just need the `@Before` annotation
- your `entityManagerMock.createNamedQuery` needs to return a mock `Query` object, the code you pasted should not even compile

In the end, your test should look something like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UsersControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UsersController usersController;

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManagerMock;

    @Mock
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Mock
    private Cache emfCache;

    @Mock
    private Query findAllQuery;

    private List<User> mockUsersDbCollection = //...

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(entityManagerFactory.getCache())
            .thenReturn(emfCache);
        when(entityManagerMock.getEntityManagerFactory())
            .thenReturn(entityManagerFactory);
        when(entityManagerMock.createNamedQuery("User.findAll"))
            .thenReturn(findAllQuery);
        when(findAllQuery.getResultList())
            .thenReturn(mockUsersDbCollection);
    }

    @Test
    public void findOneTest(){
        mockUsersDbCollection.add(new User("1", "pa$$word", "salt", "user1", "user1@email.com", false));

        User returnedUser = usersController.getOne();

        assertEquals(returnedUser.getId(), "1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am however still getting an issue. I have a null pointer exception when calling `em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();` but I thought that the entityManager had been mocked out?

Comment: Yep - missed that line. Remember that the default behaviour for all mocks is to do nothing and return `null` or `0` where appropriate.